# What kind of Epilobium is this?

Tags: identification

I've got the following *Epilobium* in my garden that I fail to properly identify:

[image] [image]

At first I thought that it was *Epilobium parviflorum*, because the flower seems similar and most of the description also fits: the ones with flowers I have are 20-70cm in height, the stem is erect, round (no distinct edge) and densely covered with hairs, the leaves are opposite, lanceolate and toothed.

However the pictures of *parviflorum* didn't quite match: the stem and leaves of the ones I have often have a reddish brown hue, the leaves seem even more lanceolate than *parviflorum*. The flowers range from pale pink or pale purple to white (maybe the pink/purple is just that faint). Also what bugs me the most is that some of the flowers I have grow in a 30yo concrete & stone wall while some others grow between said wall and the pavement's asphalt: I read that *parviflorum* generally prefers marshes, swamps and moist meadows while this one grows in rock and seemingly didn't have any issue with the exceptionally hot spring for the region (Brittany, France).

I wanted to dry the leaves and use them for infusions - apparently most *Epilobium* are safe for consumption (this one isn't really exposed to cars) and the ones that look like *parviflorum* seem to share the same properties. Does anyone know which species of *Epilobium* this is and whether it should be safe for consumption?